CFD Navier-Stokes Equation in Julia
so below is the code snippet i have for Julia:
using Printf
using Plots
gr()

# Parameters definition
Ny = 21                   # Number of points in y-direction
Aspect_ratio = 10         # Ratio of channel length to width
Re = 100                  # Reynolds number
dt = 0.008                # Time step
N_steps = 2000            # Total number of time steps
Plot_freq = 20            # Plot save frequency

Poisson_max_iter = 1000   # Total number of pressure-poisson iterations
tol = 1e-4                # Tolerance for pressure-poisson

# Function to compute an error in L2 norm
function l2_err(u1, u2)
    return sqrt(sum((u1 .- u2).^2))
end

# Generating the 2D grid
function ndgrid(x_range, y_range)
    Nx = length(x_range)
    Ny = length(y_range)
    coordinates_x = zeros(Nx, Ny)
    coordinates_y = zeros(Nx, Ny)
    for i in 1:Nx
        for j in 1:Ny
            coordinates_x[i, j] = x_range[i]
            coordinates_y[i, j] = y_range[j]
        end
    end
    return coordinates_x, coordinates_y
end

# Pressure-Poisson using the Jacobi method
function jacobi_method(p0, b, dx, dy, tolerance, max_it)
    pnew = copy(p0)
    it = 0
    err = 1.0

    while err > tolerance && it < max_it
        p = copy(pnew)

        # Calculate p_new for interior points
        pnew[2:end-1, 2:end-1] = 0.25 * (
            p[3:end, 2:end-1] + p[1:end-2, 2:end-1] + p[2:end-1, 3:end] + p[2:end-1, 1:end-2] -
            dx^2 * b[2:end-1, 2:end-1]
        )

        # Apply boundary conditions
        pnew[1, 2:end-1] .= pnew[2, 2:end-1]
        pnew[end, 2:end-1] .= -pnew[end-1, 2:end-1]
        pnew[:, 1] .= pnew[:, 2]
        pnew[:, end] .= pnew[:, end-1]

        err = l2_err(pnew, p)
        it += 1
    end

    return pnew
end

# Computing diffusion, convection, and pressure gradient terms
function compute_diffusion(u, v, dx, dy, Re)
    diffusion_x = (u[3:end, 2:end-1] - 2u[2:end-1, 2:end-1] + u[1:end-2, 2:end-1]) / dx^2 +
                  (u[2:end-1, 3:end] - 2u[2:end-1, 2:end-1] + u[2:end-1, 1:end-2]) / dy^2
    diffusion_y = (v[3:end, 2:end-1] - 2v[2:end-1, 2:end-1] + v[1:end-2, 2:end-1]) / dx^2 +
                  (v[2:end-1, 3:end] - 2v[2:end-1, 2:end-1] + v[2:end-1, 1:end-2]) / dy^2
    return diffusion_x / Re, diffusion_y / Re
end

function compute_convection(u, v, dx, dy)
    convection_x = u[2:end-1, 2:end-1] .* (u[3:end, 2:end-1] - u[1:end-2, 2:end-1]) / (2dx) +
                   v[2:end-1, 2:end-1] .* (u[2:end-1, 3:end] - u[2:end-1, 1:end-2]) / (2dy)
    convection_y = u[2:end-1, 2:end-1] .* (v[3:end, 2:end-1] - v[1:end-2, 2:end-1]) / (2dx) +
                   v[2:end-1, 2:end-1] .* (v[2:end-1, 3:end] - v[2:end-1, 1:end-2]) / (2dy)
    return convection_x, convection_y
end

function compute_pressure_gradient(pressure, dx, dy)
    pressure_gradient_x = (pressure[3:end, 2:end-1] - pressure[1:end-2, 2:end-1]) / (2dx)
    pressure_gradient_y = (pressure[2:end-1, 3:end] - pressure[2:end-1, 1:end-2]) / (2dy)
    return pressure_gradient_x, pressure_gradient_y
end

# Incompressible Navier Stokes Function
function main()

    # Make an equidistant grid of dx=dy=0.1
    cell_length = 2.0 / (Ny - 1)
    Nx = (Ny - 1) * Aspect_ratio + 1

    # Create grid
    x_range = range(0.0, stop=2.0 * Aspect_ratio, length=Nx)
    y_range = range(-1.0, stop=1.0, length=Ny)

    # Generate a 2D grid
    coordinates_x, coordinates_y = ndgrid(x_range, y_range)

    # Initial conditions
    u_prev = ones(Nx, Ny + 1)  # u^*(t^* = 0) = 1
    u_prev[:, 1] .= -u_prev[:, 2]  # No-slip boundary at bottom wall
    u_prev[:, end] .= -u_prev[:, end-1]  # No-slip boundary at top wall

    v_prev = zeros(Nx + 1, Ny)  # v^*(t^* = 0) = 0

    pressure_prev = zeros(Nx + 1, Ny + 1)  # p^*(t^* = 0) = 0

    # Pre-Allocate some arrays
    u_int = zeros(size(u_prev))
    u_next = zeros(size(u_prev))

    v_int = zeros(size(v_prev))
    v_next = zeros(size(v_prev))

    # Initialize empty array to store frames
    frames = []

    for iter in 1:N_steps
        # Compute the diffusion, convection and pressure gradient terms
        diffusion_x, diffusion_y = compute_diffusion(u_prev, v_prev, cell_length, cell_length, Re)
        convection_x, convection_y = compute_convection(u_prev, v_prev, cell_length, cell_length)
        pressure_gradient_x, pressure_gradient_y = compute_pressure_gradient(pressure_prev, cell_length, cell_length)

        # Update intermediate velocities
        u_int[2:end-1, 2:end-1] = u_prev[2:end-1, 2:end-1] + dt * (
            diffusion_x - convection_x - pressure_gradient_x
        )

        v_int[2:end-1, 2:end-1] = v_prev[2:end-1, 2:end-1] + dt * (
            diffusion_y - convection_y - pressure_gradient_y
        )

        # Apply BC on u
        u_int[:, 1] .= -u_int[:, 2]
        u_int[:, end] .= -u_int[:, end-1]
        u_int[1, :] .= 1.0
        u_int[end, :] .= u_int[end-1, :]

        # Apply BC on v
        v_int[:, 1] .= -v_int[:, 2]
        v_int[:, end] .= -v_int[:, end-1]
        v_int[1, :] .= 0.0
        v_int[end, :] .= 0.0

        # Compute the divergence as it will be the rhs of the Pressure-Poisson
        divergence = (u_int[2:end-1, 2:end-1] - u_int[1:end-2, 2:end-1]) / cell_length +
                     (v_int[2:end-1, 2:end-1] - v_int[2:end-1, 1:end-2]) / cell_length
        pressure_poisson_rhs = divergence / dt

        # Solve the pressure correction poisson problem
        pressure_correction_prev = zeros(size(pressure_prev))
        pressure_correction_next = jacobi_method(pressure_correction_prev, pressure_poisson_rhs,
                                                 cell_length, cell_length, tol, Poisson_max_iter)
        
        # Update the pressure
        pressure_next = pressure_prev + pressure_correction_next

        # Correct the velocities to be incompressible
        pressure_correction_gradient_x, pressure_correction_gradient_y = compute_pressure_gradient(pressure_correction_next, cell_length, cell_length)
        u_next[2:end-1, 2:end-1] .= u_int[2:end-1, 2:end-1] - dt * pressure_correction_gradient_x
        v_next[2:end-1, 2:end-1] .= v_int[2:end-1, 2:end-1] - dt * pressure_correction_gradient_y

        # Enforce mass conservation
        u_next[1, 2:end-1] .= 1.0
        inflow_mass_rate_next = sum(u_next[1, 2:end-1])
        outflow_mass_rate_next = sum(u_next[end-1, 2:end-1])
        u_next[end, 2:end-1] .= u_next[end-1, 2:end-1] * inflow_mass_rate_next / outflow_mass_rate_next

        # Again apply BC 
        u_next[:, 1] .= -u_next[:, 2]
        u_next[:, end] .= -u_next[:, end-1]

        v_next[1, 2:end-1] .= 0.0
        v_next[end, 2:end-1] .= 0.0
        v_next[:, 1] .= -v_next[:, 2]
        v_next[:, end] .= -v_next[:, end-1]

        # Compute error between u_prev and u_next
        err_u = l2_err(u_prev, u_next)
        println("Iteration $iter, Error in u: $err_u")

        if err_u < 1e-8
            println("Converged at iteration $iter")
            break
        end

        # Advance in time
        u_prev .= u_next
        v_prev .= v_next
        pressure_prev .= pressure_next

        # Visualization
        if iter % Plot_freq == 0
            u_centered = (u_next[:, 2:end] + u_next[:, 1:end-1]) / 2

            # Velocity plot
            p1 = plot(coordinates_x, coordinates_y, u_centered, st=:surface, title="Velocity Field", xlabel="x", ylabel="y")

            # Pressure plot
            p2 = plot(coordinates_x, coordinates_y, pressure_next, st=:surface, title="Pressure Field", xlabel="x", ylabel="y")

            # Combine both plots
            p = plot(p1, p2, layout = @layout [a; b])

            # Push the current frame to the frames array
            push!(frames, deepcopy(p))
        end
    end

    # Create the animation from the stored frames
    anim = @animate for frame in frames
        plot(frame)
    end

    return anim
end

# Initialize and run the solver
animation = main()


but it always returns the error
{
    "name": "DimensionMismatch",
    "message": "DimensionMismatch: arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 200 and 199",
    "stack": "DimensionMismatch: arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 200 and 199

Stacktrace:
 [1] _bcs1
   @ ./broadcast.jl:555 [inlined]
 [2] _bcs
   @ ./broadcast.jl:549 [inlined]
 [3] broadcast_shape
   @ ./broadcast.jl:543 [inlined]
 [4] combine_axes
   @ ./broadcast.jl:524 [inlined]
 [5] instantiate
   @ ./broadcast.jl:306 [inlined]
 [6] materialize
   @ ./broadcast.jl:903 [inlined]
 [7] compute_convection(u::Matrix{Float64}, v::Matrix{Float64}, dx::Float64, dy::Float64)
   @ Main ~/Documents/filepath.ipynb:74
 [8] main()
   @ Main ~/Documents/filepath.ipynb:123
 [9] top-level scope
   @ ~/Documents/filepath.ipynb:221"
}

i've tried to ask my peers about this problem but either they don't have it or are just as clueless as i am
i'm looking forward to suggestions :-D
i just expect the code to function without any warnings/errors, at least for now

The error message says that either in your computation of convection_x or convection_y (whichever one is on the correct line), you are trying to do element-wise operations on arrays of different lengths. This is caused by the fact that uprev has size of Nx by Ny + 1, while vprev has size Nx + 1 by Ny. To fix this, you need to figure out what size everything actually needs to be for the math to line up.
